# display php variables in bootstrap Navbar

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

i want to display Usernames after login or signup in the Navbar using the function links () but the variable holding the username wont show, only displays "$acn";

```
 function links()
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
     {
         echo '         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="signup">
            <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="signup">
            <li><a href="signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>';
         }
         else
         {
           $acn= $_SESSION['username'];
        echo   '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="signup">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="signup">
            <li><a href=\"account.php\"> $acn </a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

and the function appears like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OOOO</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#signup">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <?php echo links(); ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How do i achieve this please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, if you have a string wrapped in single quotes variables will not be parsed.

`'$acn'` is just a string with the value `$acn`. `"$acn"` will be parsed to be the value of the `$acn` variable.

Please also note that you are echoing  the output of the `links()` function, but that function has no return value.

Answer (score 0):

While your use of `$acn` would work fine in `double quotes`it does not behave in the same manor when contained inside `single quotes`.

If you wish to use `single quotes` you must concatenate the string:

```
  <li><a href=\"account.php\"> '.$acn.' </a></li>
```

Other things to note with your code, while using `single quotes` you will not need to escape `double quotes` and also there is an `echo` inside the `links` function so its not required here: `<?php echo links(); ?>`

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem the user is describing, though you are correct that the echo is unnecessary.